# Arcore: Set feature points as points (and not as pyramids)

Tags: android, arcore, point-clouds, sceneform

I found an awesome reference from [here](https://github.com/claywilkinson/arcore-android-sdk/blob/sceneform-samples/samples/cloud_anchor_java/app/src/main/java/com/google/ar/core/examples/java/cloudanchor/sceneform/PointCloudNode.java), for customize and show AR feature points.

It works wonderful but it shows pyramids and I need to show flat white points like this:

[image]

What do I need to write to show white points instead of pyramids?

**Update:** That's what I finally did and it works great:

```
if (this.timestamp != cloud.timestamp && materialHolder.getNow(null) != null) {
        timestamp = cloud.timestamp
        val buf = cloud.points

        // Point clouds are 4 values x,y,z and a confidence value.
        numOfFeaturePoints = buf.limit() / 4

        // no features in the cloud
        if (numOfFeaturePoints < 1) {
            renderable = null
            return
        }

        if (isInProcess) {
            return
        }

        isInProcess = true


        // remove current feature points
        for (child in children) {
            child.renderable = null
        }

       // add the new feature points as dots
        val feature = Vector3()
        for (i in 0 until buf.limit() / 4) {
            // feature point
            feature.x = buf.get(i * 4)
            feature.y = buf.get(i * 4 + 1)
            feature.z = buf.get(i * 4 + 2)

            val node = Node()
            node.renderable = ShapeFactory.makeCylinder(0.01f, 0.001f, Vector3(feature.x, feature.y, feature.z), myMaterial)
            node.renderable!!.isShadowCaster = false
            node.setParent(this)

        }

        isInProcess = false
    }
```

Comment: what is isInProccess ?

Comment: @NoumanShah a flag just for not interrupt to the for loop

Comment: how do you place the anchor